# WooCommerce: Change the delivery time value if the quantity in the shopping cart exceeds the quantity in the stock

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I would like to change the value for delivery time in functions.php if the quantity in the shopping cart exceeds the quantity in the warehouse. My PHP knowledge is unfortunately very limited.

The following code has been used to create a field in the product data where you can enter a delivery time if the product is not in stock. If the stock is 0, the new delivery time will also be displayed.

The problem is that this does not change. If someone puts im more in the cart than is in stock. Then actually, the alternative delivery time should be displayed.

```
/*================================================
Lieferzeitenanzeige bei Lieferrückstand
================================================*/
add_action( 'woocommerce_process_product_meta', 'wdt_process_delivery_time_fallback', 10, 2 );
function wdt_process_delivery_time_fallback( $id, $post ){
 
    $dtf_id = $_POST['delivery_time_fallback'];
    if( $dtf_id === '' ) {
        delete_post_meta( $id, '_delivery_time_fallback' );
    } else {
        update_post_meta( $id, '_delivery_time_fallback', $dtf_id );
    }
 
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_product_options_stock_status', 'wdt_add_deliver_time_fallback' );
function wdt_add_deliver_time_fallback() {
    // Lieferzeiten aus den Terms generieren
    $delivery_times = get_terms( array(
        'taxonomy' => 'product_delivery_time',
        'hide_empty' => false,
    ) );
    $options[''] = __( 'Keine', 'woocommerce');
    foreach ($delivery_times as $key => $term) {
        $options[$term->term_id] = $term->name;
    }
    // gewählte Lieferzeit aufbereiten
    $dtf_id = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_delivery_time_fallback', true );
    // Element generieren
    woocommerce_wp_select( array(
        'id'          => 'delivery_time_fallback',
        'label'       => __('Lieferzeit bei Lieferrückstand', 'woocommerce'),
        'options'     => $options,
        'value'       => $dtf_id,
        'desc_tip' => true,
        'description' => __( 'Lieferzeit die angezeigt wird, wenn sich der Artikel im Lieferrückstand befindet.' ),
    ) );
        
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_germanized_delivery_time_backorder_html', 'wdt_adjust_delivery_time_html', 10, 4 );
function wdt_adjust_delivery_time_html( $text, $product ) {

    // this must be a variation if we can find a parent_id
    if ( $product->get_parent_id() ) {
        $id = $product->get_parent_id();
    } else {
        $id = $product->get_id();
    }
    
    // let's try to find the parent delivery time in postmeta
    if ( metadata_exists( 'post', $id, '_delivery_time_fallback' ) ) {

        $delivery_times = get_terms( array(
            'taxonomy' => 'product_delivery_time',
            'hide_empty' => false,
        ) );

        $dtf_id = get_post_meta( $id, '_delivery_time_fallback', true );

        foreach ($delivery_times as $dtf) {
            if ( $dtf->term_id == $dtf_id) {
                $delivery_time = $dtf->name;
                break;
            }
        }

    } else {
        $delivery_time = '1-2 Wochen ab Bestelldatum';
    }
    return 'Lieferzeit: '.$delivery_time;

}
```

To compare the cart with the stock I already have the following:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_stock_now' ); 
  
  function woocommerce_stock_now() {
        global $product;
        $stocknow = $product->get_stock_quantity();
        ?>
        <script>
              jQuery(document).on('input change','[name=quantity]',function() {
                    var stocknow = '<?php echo $stocknow; ?>';
                    var qtyinput = jQuery(this).val(); 
                    var overdue = parseInt(qtyinput) - parseInt(stocknow);
                    if (parseInt(qtyinput) > parseInt(stocknow)){
        </script>
        <?php 
  }
```

What else do I need to add to change the value of delivery time?

In addition to WooCommerce, the plugin "Germanized" is in use.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What is the exact issue? please add the full code.

Comment: I have now added the full code above.

The problem is that this does not change. If someone puts im more in the cart than is in stock. Then actually, the alternative delivery time should be displayed.

Comment: still code is not complete for `woocommerce_single_product_summary` hook.